# Redux Usage Issue @connect

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am learning redux from this tutorial 
[source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrg7zhgJd4w&list=PLoYCgNOIyGADILc3iUJzygCqC8Tt3bRXt&index=7) (05:50)

and have this issue with @connect

```
Failed to compile

./src/component/Layout.jsx
Syntax error: Unexpected token (4:0)

  2 | import { connect } from 'react-redux'
  3 | 
> 4 | @connect()
    | ^
  5 | class Layout extends Component {
  6 |   render () {
  7 |       return null
```

and this is the end of my tutorial.

I do not know how to use webpack, and here I do not see any explanations about it.

Comment: Decorator syntax `@connect` is a stage 2 proposal to ES. This means that you have to configure your transpiler (probably babel) so that it can handle decorator syntax. http://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-decorators

Comment: I would expect that there should be some explanation of how to set up babel/webpack in the tutorial, since decorators are not a standard feature yet, you need to explicitly enable it, as explained in the link in my other comment. On the other hand, decorators are just syntactic sugar. The result will be exactly the same if you just call `connect()` as a function, (the accepted answer in the suggested duplicate). https://stackoverflow.com/a/45696026/1977847

Comment: I don't think the suggested duplicate answer really answers the question.

Comment: now i have this error

Failed to compile.

./src/component/Layout.jsx
  Line 9:   'store' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 10:  'store' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 11:  'store' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Then ask a new question. These are two completely independent errors. And include all relevant code, not just the error message. [mcve]