# React-redux connect HOC as a class decorator, @connect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, ecmascript-next

I have a component wrapped using the [ES+ proposed decorator syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/%22decorator%20syntax%22) form of react-redux's connect HOC:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import RegisterForm from './register-form';
import { registerUser } from '../store/api/Auth/actions';

@connect(null, { registerUser: registerUser })
export default class RegisterPage extends Component {
  handleSubmit = values =>
    this.props.registerUser(values);

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Register Here</h1>
        <RegisterForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm receiving an error:

```
Uncaught Error: You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received {"kind":"class","elements":[{"kind":"field","key":"handleSubmit","placement":"own","descriptor":{"configurable":true,"writable":true,"enumerable":false}},{"kind":"method","key":"render","placement":"prototype","descriptor":{"writable":true,"configurable":true,"enumerable":false}}]}
```

I'm using Webpack 4 with babel-loader. My .babelrc file is:

```
{
  "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "decoratorsBeforeExport": true }]
    ]
}
```

It seems to me that the target object of the connect function is the class, but the connect function is receiving the property descriptors of that class. I understand that decorators are discouraged by the React and Redux teams. This is a related SO question: [React-Redux @connect syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45695981/react-redux-connect-syntax-error)

How can I get the @connect decorator to work?

Comment: As you noted, we do indeed discourage use of decorators in general, and specifically using `connect` as a decorator.  The decorator syntax and plugins are still unstable and continuing to change.

Comment: @markerikson Thanks for the reply. Having seen others using it, I'm curious what I'm missing to get it working.

Comment: It's a constantly changing landscape. If you're so bent on using something that is not officially supported, then you need to go the extra mile. You'd need to find a version of babel-plugin-transform-decorators (or -legacy) that can make this work. You may also have to find matching versions of other babel plugins that can work in _that_ ecosystem. Chasing this idea is good for science though, so good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you inject decorator plugin before plugin class properties

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

[babel-plugin-proposal-decorators](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators)

Comment: Please add some information/description/context about the linked resource

Comment: Still I get descriptor as first and only parameter to decorator function.